# AngularJS: Redirect to Login Page when authentication fails

Tags: angularjs

Is this a correct way to redirect ti login page if password and username are incorrect?

```
 when('/dashboard', {
          resolve:{
            "check": function($location,$rootScope,$cookieStore)
            {
                if(!$cookieStore.get('token'))
                {
                    $location.path("/login");
                }
            }
          },
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/index.html',
        //controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        //controllerAs: 'about'
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
.when('/viewprojects', {
        templateUrl: '/views/projects.html',
        controller: 'ProjectViewController',
        resolve: {
          authenticate: authenticateCb
        }
      })
```

Where `authenticateCb` is:

```
/**
     * A callback to authenticate routes navigation.
     * @param   {Object} Authenticator Authentication service
     * @returns {Object} authenticated promise.
     */
    var authenticateCb = function (AuthenticatorService) {
      return AuthenticatorService.authenticated();
    };
```

AuthenticatorService goes as follows:

```
function AuthenticatorService($q, $rootScope, $location, NotifierService, ViewPath) {
    /**
     * Authentics the user on route changes and navigate to corresponding
     * view. If the user is not authenticated then it naviagtes the user
     * to Log in page.
     * @returns {Object} authenticated promise.
     */
    this.authenticated = function () {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      if ($rootScope.token) {
        deferred.resolve('Authenticated.');
      } else {
        NotifierService.notify('PLEASE_LOGIN_AGAIN', 'error');
        $location.path(ViewPath.LOGIN_PAGE);
        deferred.reject();
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    };
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

No. It should return a `promise` to resolve the route. For example

**the routing configuration that will use the service in a resolve.**

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/news", {
        templateUrl: "newsView.html",
        controller: "newsController",
        resolve: {
            greeting: function(greetingService){
               return greetingService.getGreeting();
            }
        }
})
```

**the following simple `greetingService` which uses $q to simulate the async work required to fetch some data.**

```
app.factory("greetingService", function($q, $timeout){
   return {
       getGreeting: function(){
           var deferred = $q.defer();
           $timeout(function(){
               deferred.resolve("Allo!");
           },2000);
           return deferred.promise;
       }
   }
});
```

This will resolve your route.

Hope it helps.